# How to implement a "Ready, Set, Go" modal using Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing an Angular 5/typescript application.

Before the user is presented with a form I would like the words "ready", "set", "go" to be flashed up on screen before the user can start. Each word/dialog/modal would be displayed for a small amount of time (say, 1 second), requiring no user interaction to close.

I have little experience with Angular and typescript so would welcome any possible solution to how to implement this feature?

Many thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to utilize the [interval](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html) function from the [rxjs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) library which you can easily import into your angular project.

Here's a possible example for your reference

```
let words = ['Ready', 'Set', 'Go'];
Observable.interval(1000)
    .take(3)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        console.log(i); 
        console.log(words[0]); // note just simplified here, you probably need to add more logic to handle the animation etc
    })
```

So the above is the just a quick example on how you can achieve this by using interval function.

Alternatively, you can go with window.setInterval function as well. I am not going to add an example for it here. You can read a bit more on this via  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great starting point, I will try them both. Much appreciated.

Comment: @carth no worries. happy to help. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @woodykiddy for the suggestion of rxjs. Within my MatDialog component, I subscribed to a sequence and closed the dialog from the finally callback:

```
    private readyTitle: string;

    displayRSG() {    
        let words = ['Ready', 'Set', 'Go!', ''];
        const intrval = interval(900);
        const sequence = intrval.pipe(take(4));           
        const sub = sequence
            .finally(() => {
              console.log('Finally callback')
              this.closeDialog();          
            })
            .subscribe(i => {         
            this.readyTitle = words[i];     
            })
      }
```

...with `{{readyTitle}}` variable bound to my mat-dialog-title in the html template.